# How to get a access token in jwt format using the previously fetched access token in opaque format

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory, access-token, azure-ad-graph-api

I have three application S1, S2 (web API), S3(web API)  using the S1 I made a sign-in request and fetched id token in jwt format and access token in opaque format. now I used the same token to access S2 and validated against the Azure Ad using user-info endpoint. now from S2, I want to use the same access token to access the S3 but S3 is restricted to jwt format.so tell me the way how I can fetch an access token in jwt format using the opaque format access token against the resource S3.

Comment: Is On-behalf-Of flow what you need? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow

Comment: Yes, but there is some issue with that. when I am requesting the token by passing all the parameters like grant_type and assertion I am getting an error that  the jwt is malformed or invalid. Beacuse I am passing the token in opaque format this flow is restricted to the jwt format only

Comment: Can you provide more details of your issue?

Comment: To use On-behalf-Of flow I need assertion in jwt format so for that I need to convert access token from opaque format to jwt format. If You required screenshots or other details please let me know I will Provide

Comment: What is an access token in opaque format? As far as I know, Azure access tokens are JWTs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens).  Could you please add some concept maps so that we can have a better understanding of your issue ?

Comment: "AQABAAAAAAAP0wLlqdLVToOpA4kwzSnxBUI8cuy_boVoRO9G ..(shotened to insert).....J18Hdu10PxJgWCibZxClE3nvYY7IXKkGHp3jkY2Wmjb3p4GntEQNycX9iJ4nNzfDwa_ITFiljZkP-jiuJObsegg-ila4JJexhXkEpvViTERU_GUofkjYSLQXvrda_HOQgAA" this is the access token in opaque format if i use this token to hit userinfo endpoint i will get the information of the user if user is authenticated and access token is valid. now my user is authenticated so i want to use same token to tel ad that this is my access token i am a valid user , issue me a new access token for another resource i have access for.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are a bit mixing terms and contexts.

First, there is no opaque format. To access an API (whether yours, or Microsoft) you need an `access token`. There are various flows to get an access token. Out of all, you are referring here to the [on-behalf-of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) flow. Everything is good, untill the point that you try to use a `refresh token` instead of the `access token` in your request for a new `access token`.

Refresh token usage is also explained in the [docs I mention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow). The point is, a `refresh token` can only and solely be used in the client credentials flow to get a new `access token`.

[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code#refreshing-the-access-tokens) explains how to use refresh token to get a new access token. But do not confuse the [on-behalf-of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) with [refreshing access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code#refreshing-the-access-tokens).

These are two completely different flows, serving completely different purposes. Every time you need to get an `access token` to access a **new** resource (another API), you need the `on-behalf-of` flow. And every time you need to **refresh** an *expired* `access token` you use the `refresh access token` flow.

Now, if you used an `access_token` obtained in S1 to access S2 - this is correct way to do this. And the last step - to access S3 from S2 you need to:

Use the [on-behalf-of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) flow to obtain **new** `access token` for S3. To do this you need to:

1. Make sure that S2 is authorized to access S3 (i.e. [as documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/notifications-integration-app-registration#api-permissions), but instead of Graph you will have to chose S3).
2. Use the `access token` received in the request from S1 to S2 as the `client assertion` as [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#service-to-service-access-token-request)
3. Use the so obtained `access token` to call S3

Comment: "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": "3600",
    "ext_expires_in": "3600",
    "expires_on": "1565706563",
    "access_token": "AQABAAAAAAAP0wLlqdLVToOpA4kwzSnxBUI8cuy_boVoRO9GM4iN-t2HybVKw47iTIyqP6tal1.....GntEQNycX9iJ4nNzfDwa_ITFiljZkP-jiuJObsegg-ila4JJexhXkEpvViTERU_GUofkjYSLQXvrda_HOQgAA",
    "refresh_token": "AQABAAAAAAAP0wLlqdLVToOpA4kwzSnx1QJm9-RsxFTL_beIRKvmPAA9rbfx4s92ZBV......P7DoGSIHRMRjCyjzr8OCn8yIbH3W......O9g3VNo_DbfyCYpo_BzVcu1dJ8-9UvYNIAA"

Comment: this is the response i got and i am not misxing the concept , there are two formats of token one is jwt and other is opaque. somehow I managed to fetch token in opaque format from microsoft and now i want to use the same token to request new token in jwt format because my user is already authenticated.

Comment: update your question with all the steps and requests / responses **at each step** in order to help you further. There is no such thing as "opaque format". Access tokens in general should be interpreted as Opaque strings for the client. They are only intended for the resource server to interpret them.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. My access token looks just like the one you show and it certainly is not a JWT. Can anyone shed light on what is wrong with this or how to get the JWT version of the token?

Comment: hey @TerryH Somehow  I managed to get the jwt version for the same. Can you explain the use case of your token ? on the basis of that i will provide you the correct implementation without compromising the security